# Change jQuery load relative url

Tags: jquery, load, base-url

I need a little help with this...I'm not too familiar with jQuery (still learning), and so not sure if this is even possible.

I've basically loaded a section of a page using
    $("#my-div").load("http://www.demo.com #container")

The contents of #container load just find in #my-div. The problem is, the links loaded are relative and therefor invalid.

Is there as way to alter the content loaded such that the url can be changed from something like this:

```
<a href="/this/sample-link-to-page">sample link</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/this/sample-link-to-page">sample link</a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
$("#my-div a").each( function(index){
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    link = 'http://mysite.com' + link;
    $(this).attr('href', link);
});
```

You get all the links, then iterate over changing them.

Comment: This will work fine if links already exist on the page, but doesn't seem to change the links loaded using .load

Comment: Maybe you should put this snippet inside a funtion and call them after   if finish loading, use the **complete** handler in load() function. [Jquery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Carlos487 - Thank you - Can't vote up due to reputation (new). It worked perfect.

Comment: Great @Stangn99 I'm glad it help. And don't worry you can also accept your answer so it can help others